# Obtener el valor de un campo del XmlRequest de un servicio en SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, xml

Necesito obtener el valor de `name="solicitud"` que sería 123456 del siguiente request de un servicio que está en un campo XML de una tabla.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:execute xmlns:ns1="FrontEndDispatcher" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <userSessionId xsi:type="xsd:long">31111432</userSessionId>
      <transaction xsi:type="xsd:string">Datos.getEasy</transaction>
      <parameters xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Array" ns2:arrayType="xsd:anyType[4]">
        <item xmlns:ns3="http://nca.siderar.com/xml-soap" xsi:type="ns3:DataTable">
          <dt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="valores">
            <r>
              <c name="solicitud" xsi:type="xsd:string">123456</c>
              <c name="reversionado" xsi:type="xsd:string">S</c>
            </r>
          </dt>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">1</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">ASA</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string" />
      </parameters>
      <includeSchema xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</includeSchema>
    </ns1:execute>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Este XML lo almacene en una variable @XmlEnviado y quiero almacenar el valor de name="solicitud" en mi variable @Solicitud.

Intente los siguiente pero no me sale

```
    DECLARE @XmlEnviado XML;
    DECLARE @Solicitud  INT;
                
    SET @XmlEnviado = (SELECT XmlEnviado FROM TablaLog WHERE Id = 21)
    SET @Solicitud =  @XmlEnviado.value('(/parameters/item/dt/r/c/@solicitud)[0]', 'int' )  
    SELECT @Solicitud
```

Ayuda pf

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución:

```
SELECT r.value('c[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS solicitud
       ,r.value('c[2]','CHAR') AS reversionado
FROM @XmlEnviado.nodes('/:Envelope/:Body/:execute/:parameters/:item/:dt/*:r') AS A(r)
```

Esa linea de código me muestra los valores del nodo **r**.

Recuerden que todo ese request lo tiene mi variable **@XmlEnviado**

Una forma abreviada es también la siguiente:

```
SELECT r.value('c[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS solicitud
       ,r.value('c[2]','CHAR') AS reversionado
FROM @XmlEnviado.nodes('//*:r') AS A(r)
```